# How can I run initial subroutine after opening new window

Tags: perl, perltk

In my Perl/Tk script I'm opening new windows, and i want the window opening will run an initial subroutine (when ever the window is opened) 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call the subroutine from the code that creates and/or raises the window. If you want the call to be bound to the *action* itself rather than the *invocation* of that action (maybe because the window could be opened from multiple places in the code) you would need to create an event binding. e.g.

```
$window->bind('<Map>', \&mysub);
```

Depending on what precisely you're trying to do, you might want to bind to the `Create`, `Activate`, or `Visibility` events instead. See the [Tk event type documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm#M7) for more information.